# How to get $\int_{|t|>\epsilon}\frac{f(x-t)}{t}\ dt=\int_{\epsilon<|t|<R}\frac{f(x-t)-f(x)}{t}\ dt$ where $f$ is smooth and supported on $[-R,R]$?

Tags: real-analysis, harmonic-analysis

> Suppose $f:{\bf R}\to{\bf R}$ is sufficiently smooth and supported on $[-R,R]$. Then $$
> \int_{|t|>\epsilon}\frac{f(x-t)}{t}\ dt=\int_{\epsilon<|t|<R}\frac{f(x-t)-f(x)}{t}\ dt\ .\tag{*}$$

In his lecture notes on [Hilbert transform](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~tao/247a.1.06f/notes4.pdf), Tao makes a one-line calculation as follows:

> [image]

Writing $\{|t|>\epsilon\}$ as a union of $(-\infty,-\epsilon]$ and $[\epsilon,\infty)$, playing around with the change of variable $u=x-t$ back and forth on the left hand side of ($*$), I got
$$
\int_{\epsilon<|t|<R}\frac{f(x-t)}{t}\ dt
+\int_{R}^{R+x}\frac{f(x-t)}{t}\ dt
-\int_{-R}^{-R+\epsilon}\frac{f(x-t)}{t}\ dt,
$$
which is not quite the right hand side yet. It seems that the calculation would be very simple by using "symmetry" as indicated in the notes. But I don't know how. Would anyone elaborate how it is done (by symmetry)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually quite simple. You first take $R$ large enough so that $f(x-t) = 0$ if $|t| > R$, which is possible, since $f$ has compact support. So the integral becomes $\int_{\epsilon < |t| < R} \frac{f(x-t)}{t}dt$. Now note $\int_{\epsilon < |t| < R} \frac{f(x)}{t}dt = 0$ (by symmetry) since $f(x)$ is just a constant. You're done.

Comment: Very nice! I didn't notice that one can choose larger $R$ to make the calculation much easier.